# Change data source of a list table in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Is there a way to change the data source of a list table in Excel? It's easy to change the data source of a pivot table but the only way I have found to change the data source of a list table is to delete the table and start again.

Just to be clear, what I mean by a list table is what you get when you set up a connection to a table or query in Access (for example) and then click on "Existing Connections" under the Data tab.

I would prefer a method using the usual user interface but if there is a method that works only in VBA, that would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from the Excel interface without VBA.

Under the Data tab, click on Connections.

From the Workbook Connections dialog, click Properties.

From the Connection Properties dialog, click Definition.

Browse for a connection file and then select a table.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you Excel Hero. This doesn't quite work for me because I use a connection string rather than a file but it's the same idea. So for a pivot table I can swap connections in and out, but for a list table I need to edit the connection. This is fine because every list table has its own connection, unlike pivot tables, several of which can run off one connection.

Answer (score 0):

If your data source is inside Excel on another sheet and you're using OLE DB Query, you might find changing the data source impossible (which was the case with me).

To change the data source in this instance, you need to click on `Resize Table` under the Table Design tab in Excel, as can be seen below:

[image: Excel Ribbon]

When you click on this, you are able to change the range of your query, as can be seen below:

[image: Resizing the Table]